# Why app runs locally but it doesn't on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle, playframework

I have application (Playframework + Angular4) which is build using Gradle+Webpack. When I run my app locally, it works fine:

```
user@debian:~/workspace$ ./gradlew :dist :api:runapi
....
--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

> Task :api:runPlayBinary
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd                           -Dsun.java2d.xrender=true
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9999
<===========--> 85% EXECUTING [1m 46s]
> :api:runPlayBinary > Running at http://localhost:9000/
```

So, the Netty started, everything is good. The terminal is waiting... And the app is accessible.

But, when I try to make the same but using Jenkins, I get the following logs:

```
13:53:33 :api:createPlayBinaryAssetsJar
13:53:39 :api:compilePlayBinaryPlayRoutes
13:53:45 :api:compilePlayBinaryScala
13:53:45 Pruning sources from previous analysis, due to incompatible CompileSetup.
13:53:54 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/imaster/api/app/controllers/UserController.scala:27: match may not be exhaustive.
13:53:54 It would fail on the following input: None
13:53:54     users.getById(id).map { case Some(user) =>
13:53:54                           ^
13:54:02 there were 3 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
13:54:02 two warnings found
13:54:04 :api:processPlayBinaryPlayResources
13:54:04 :api:createPlayBinaryJar
13:54:04 :api:playBinary
13:54:04 :api:runPlayBinary
13:54:04 Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9999
13:54:05 [35m--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---[0m
13:54:05 
13:54:06 [[37minfo[0m] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
13:54:06 :api:runapi
13:54:06 
13:54:06 BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 54s
13:54:06 11 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 2 up-to-date
13:54:07 Finished: SUCCESS
```

There are not any errors, but Netty looks like stopped(it doesn't wait as in example above), and when I try to access to localhost:9000 I get "Server not found".

I tried to run app manually, from the Jenkins workspace directory, it works.

How can I run Netty using Gradle and Jenkins?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think about Docket, to deploy docket container and run it Jenkins, but maybe is there another solution?

Comment: maybe the issue with ipv6 on jenkins ( Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000)?

Comment: It is not a reason